# To Count the number of columns in a CSV file using python 2.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-2.4

I want to count the total number of columns in a CSV file. Currently i am using python 2.7 and 3.4. Code works perfectly in these versions and when i try to implement the same thing in python 2.4, it is showing as next() is not defined.

Code i am using currently(2.7 and 3.4)

```
f = open(sys.argv[1],'r')

reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=d)

num_cols = len(next(reader)) # Read first line and count columns
```

My strong need is to implement the same in **Python 2.4** . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about it doesn't work in Python 2.4? The `csv` module has been in the standard library since 2.3.

Comment: Does `reader.next()` work? The [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) builtin is new in Python 2.6.

Comment: i want to get the total number of columns in the csv file using python 2.4..  i think next() function is not defined in 2.4.. please guide  me in regarding this...

Comment: i tried with readlines and split function also..it is not working

Comment: I meant [`reader.next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.next). This should have been available in 2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have Python 2.4 installed at the moment, so I can not really test this.

According to the documentation, the [`next` builtin is new in Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next). However, the `csv.reader` has a [`next` method of it's own](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.next), and that one seems to have existed even in 2.4, so you should be able to use this.

```
num_cols = len(reader.next())
```

Answer (score 0):

assume you get a csv like this

> test1,test2,test3

you can do like this

```
file = open("test.csv","r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
lenCol = len(next(reader))
A = ["A"+str(i) for i in range(1,lenCol+1)]
```