# What could I use instead of next() in python 2.4

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools, python-2.4

I need to emulate `izip_longest` from `itertools` in Python 2.4

```
import itertools
class Tools:
    @staticmethod
    def izip_longest(*args, **kwds):
        # izip_longest('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By C- D-
        fillvalue = kwds.get('fillvalue')
        counter = [len(args) - 1]
        def sentinel():
            if not counter[0]:
                raise ZipExhausted
            counter[0] -= 1
            yield fillvalue
        fillers = itertools.repeat(fillvalue)
        iterators = [itertools.chain(it, sentinel(), fillers) for it in args]
        try:
        while iterators:
            yield tuple(map(next, iterators))
        except ZipExhausted:
            pass       


class ZipExhausted(Exception):
    pass
```

Everything works fine, until I reach `yield tuple(map(next, iterators))`;
Python 2.4 throws a

```
NameError: global name 'next' is not defined
```

error and quits.

What could I use instead of `next` to make `izip_longest` run in Python 2.4?

Or is there any other function in Python 2.4 which returns the same result as `izip_longest()`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a class with a static method? Why not just make that a function instead?

Comment: Somewhat related (not exactly a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/25810855/1639625

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) was added to Python 2.6. Use the `next` method from the iterators instead:

```
while iterators:
    yield tuple([it.next() for it in iterators])
```

or define your own `next()` function; you are not using the `default` argument, so for your simpler case that'd be:

```
def next(it):
    return it.next()
```

but the full version would be:

```
_sentinel = object()

def next(it, default=_sentinel):
    try:
        return it.next()
    except StopIteration:
        if default is _sentinel:
            raise
        return default
```